# Mercurial: pushing files changed from an outside source

Tags: mercurial

In know this is a convoluted scenario but this is my situation. We have 
files (*.doc) being updated and posted to SharePoint. I want them in Mercurial. We've have a script that exports these files to a windows share that is marked as a mercurial repository (cloned) with the intention of automatically pushing the files into a central mercurial repository.

The initial exportation of the files resulted in these files being marked as unversioned. A simple

```
hg add 
hg push
```

moved the files into the desired central repo. These files are automatically exported (overwriting the files) nightly to the windows share. But mercurial does not recognize any changes.

```
hg status
```

results are empty.

My question is how can I get Mercurial to recognize the changes so they can be pushed?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the file are different ? Or that they were overwritten ? If hg status results are empty, it means that the file aren't changed. There's nothing particular in your workflow that could result in a problem. If the file changed in the directory, Mercurial will see it.

Comment: @krtek Yes the files (or some of them) are different. Yes they are overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you have two repos, one a clone of the central repo. You have to consider them as separate repository from here on.
hg status only shows the difference between the `working copy` and pristine files in repo (`.hg directory`)
Bringing changes to the repo will show up in `hg log` and not `hg status`

Here is a normal procedure.

```
              +------+            +------+
              |Repo A|            |Repo B|
              +------+            +------+
 New File        |                   |
 .............>  |                   |
                 | hg add            |
                 | hg commit         |
 Files in repo A |                   |
 --------------- |                   |
                 |      hg push      |
                 |------------------ |  Files in Repo B
                 |      hg pull      |
                 |                   |  hg update
                 |                   |  hg status (empty)
                 |                   |  hg log (Will show new
                                                  version )
```

Also are MS word Doc files would be considered as binary files and you may not take great advantage of version control.

Sorry for being a bit pedantic but the difference between repo and working directory causes enough confusion. Files pulled in repo will only show up with `hg update`:

```
      +------------+                 +---------+
      |Your working|                 |Your Repo|
      |directory   |                 |.hg dir  |
      +------------+                 +---------+
            |                             |
            |        hg status            |
            |-----------------------------|
            |   shows difference between  |  hg pull <--
            |      working dir and repo   |-------------
            |                             |  <-- hg push
            |                             |     from another repo
            |                             |
            |         hg update           |  hg pull or push
            | <-------------------------- |  deals with repo
            |   This brings latest change |  and not working
            |   version from repo to      |  dir
                   working dir
```

Comment: you are correct they are two separate repos and the files being 'imported' to the local repo are being overwritten. It is also true that they are binary but our main concern is to be able to diff the changes and this is possible via TortoiseHg VisualDiff and the DocDiff tool.

Comment: Files being overwritten should not have gone through the "hg add" route at all. Only new files should have gone through "hg add". Just trying to understand what else could have gone wrong or differently. Thanks

Comment: Correct, in the initial export to the working directory, hg status and hg add worked as you expect. In any followup exports (after a user has made a change and posted to SharePoint) is where Hg is not recognizing the overwritten files as changed.

Comment: @TDF: Thats the question. If you are overwriting previously added files, you should not have needed to add it again.

Comment: Yes but the context of the file has changed. I what to push that change to the central repo.

Comment: @TDF: Sorry to take it as discussion. I hope that clarification will allow others to post answers too. Once you have committed the file in local repo and pulled the changes to central repo. You will not see the differences in hg status but in hg log. hg update will reflect the changes in working copy of the central repo.